# Using Maven Versions Plugin

Tags: java, maven, build, war

Using the following command line:

> mvn versions:unlock-snapshots dependency:copy-dependencies

I get all snapshot jars with the SNAPSHOT.jar name in the dependency folder.

Why do I don't get the same behavior when packaging my project into a war?
Instead of getting mylibs-modules-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, I get those incrementing numbers.

**EDITED**

```
<project>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>mylibs</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>3.4</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>mylibs-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</parent>

<build>
    <finalName>mylibs-war</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**PARENT POM FILE**

```
<project>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>parent</groupId>
<artifactId>mylibs</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>3.4</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.build.resourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.resourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mylibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>mylibs-tests</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mylibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>mylibs-processor</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mylibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>mylibs-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mylibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>mylibs-databean</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mylibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>mylibs-localization</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mylibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>mylibs-net</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mylibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>mylibs-lang</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mylibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>mylibs-metadata</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mylibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>mylibs-events</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mylibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>mylibs-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Its very difficult to tell why packaging works in certain way without looking at your pom

Comment: My pom is empty, it gets it's dependencies from the parent pom file, and I declared the plugins so I can call them from the command line. I just defined the group / artifact / version elements.

Comment: I run "mvn versions:unlock-snapshots package" as command line, I was expecting to get the jarnames-SNAPSHOT.jar in the war, but it's not the case.

Comment: May be you can share parent pom then because its difficult to answer without looking at pom configuration.

Comment: Added parent pom file content.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin goal is not designed to be run as part of the lifecycle per the [documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/unlock-snapshots-mojo.html).  The **Attributes** section describing the *unlock-snapshots* goal says

> Executes by direct invocation only.

This means it will only run if you type `mvn versions:unlock-snapshots` at the command line as you have been doing.

---

Just noted the comment above about how the commands are run:

`mvn versions:unlock-snapshots package`

I suspect this doesn't work because the `unlock-snapshots` goal is actually changing the POM, however the `package` phase is running with the original, unmodified version of the POM.  Perhaps running the build with `-X` will show this.